# Moving to a certain position in a ListView upon creation. (Android)

Tags: android, listview

I was wondering if it is possible to start a ListActivity and in real time decide how far down the list it should be focused on. (Example: When the activity is started it checks for certain conditions and then it may scroll down to a row partially through the list.)

Thanks,
Rob